# How can I pass a filehandle to Perl Expect's log_file function?

Tags: perl, logging, expect, filehandle

I feel stupid for asking this, but I've tried a couple things and I'm not sure where to go with it.

From the [Expect.pm documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod):

> `$object->log_file("filename" | $filehandle | \&coderef | undef)`
>
> Log session to a file. All characters send to or received from 
>   the spawned process are written to the file.

I'd like to pass the $filehandle to log_file.  However, when I tried this:

```
open (LOG, ">>" .$opt{l});
my $sess = Expect->spawn("telnet $ip");
$sess->log_file(LOG)
```

I get a file named 'LOG' in the directory that I'm running the script out of.  After some investigation, I tried this:

```
open (LOG, ">>" .$opt{l});
my $sess = Expect->spawn("telnet $ip");
my $fh = *LOG;
$sess->log_file($fh)
```

Now, I get a file named `*main::LOG` in the directory.  I do have another file as well, named whatever I specified on the `-l` option, but it only contains the lines that I send to `print LOG`.

I'm not sure if the filehandling functionality is hosed in the function, or if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Does `use strict; use warnings;` give you any clues? At least `use warnings;`?

Comment: Changed it to 'open my $log, ">>", $opt{l}', but now it's giving me the following error: "Given logfile doesn't have a 'print' method" on the line that I call $sess->log_file( $log );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a bareword filehandle named `LOG`, you can pass it to a function by saying `\*LOG` (you can read more about this in [`perldoc perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles)), but don't do that.  Bareword filehandles are a very old style and should no longer be used.  Try using a lexical filehandle and the three argument version of open:

```
open my $log, ">>", $opt{l}
    or die "could not open $opt{l}: $!";
```

you can use `$log` anywhere you used `LOG` in the past.

You should also be using the [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) pragmas.

Comment: Chas.- Thanks, that helps.  Unfortunately, I'm working with a lot of old documentation.  I learned Perl in the early 2000's, and am circling back around to it now, so I have a lot of 'old' habits.

Comment: Now I'm getting "Given logfile doesn't have a 'print' method".

Comment: It sounds like it wants a blessed filehandle.  You can get a blessed filehandle by just adding `use IO::Handle;` to the top of your program.  All lexical and bareword filehandles should be usable as objects (e.g. `$log->print("I am printing!\n")` is the same as `print $log "I am printing!\n"`).

Comment: If you are coming back into the fold, you should really read [Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735) by Conway.

Comment: Thanks for the book recommendation, I'll check it out.  But IO::Handle didn't fix the issue, unless I need to call open a different way.

Comment: This has become a different issue, I went ahead and asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721148/blessed-filehandle-doesnt-return-true-with-can

Answer (score 1):

Try using a lexical filehandle (and the three-argument `open`, and `die`) to begin with:

```
open my $logfh, ">>", $opt{l} or die "Could not open log file $opt{l}: $!\n";
$sess->log_file( $logfh );
```

`LOG` is incredibly generic and could be getting trumped (or doing the trumping) of another filehandle somewhere in your code. Using a lexical filehandle helps to prevent confusion. And you should always check the return status of `open()` (or `use autodie`) in case you can't actually open the file.

Comment: Thanks, CanSpice.  I am checking the output of 'open', just left that off in the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a better idea to return a filehandle using `log_file` by passing it the filename instead.

---

From the [Expect documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod):

> `$object->log_file("filename" | $filehandle | \&coderef | undef)`
>
> Log session to a file. All characters
>   send to or received from the spawned
>   process are written to the file.
>   Normally appends to the logfile, but
>   you can pass an additional mode of "w"
>   to truncate the file upon `open()`:
>
> `$object->log_file("filename", "w");`
>
> Returns the *logfilehandle*.

So you should be able to achieve the same functionality using the following:

```
my $sess = Expect->spawn("telnet $ip");
$sess->log_file($opt{l});               # Or my $fh = $sess->log_file...
                                        # if that filehandle is needed
```

Now all your session activity will be logged to the file. Append mode is the default.