# Why doesn't my Perl blessed filehandle doesn't return true with `can('print')`'?

Tags: perl, file, handle

For some reason, I can't get filehandles working with Expect.pm's `log_file` method.  I originally got help on [How can I pass a filehandle to Perl Expect's log_file function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719545/passing-filehandle-to-perl-expects-log-file-function), where it was suggested that I use an IO::Handle filehandle to pass to the method.  This seems to be a different issue, so I thought I'd start a new question.

This is the offending section of Expect.pm:

```
if (ref($file) ne 'CODE') {
  croak "Given logfile doesn't have a 'print' method"
    if not $fh->can("print");
  $fh->autoflush(1);        # so logfile is up to date
}
```

So, then, I tried this sample code:

```
use IO::Handle;
open $fh, ">>", "file.out" or die "Can't open file";
$fh->print("Hello, world");
if ($fh->can("print"))
{
  print "Yes\n";
}
else
{
  print "No\n";
}
```

When I run this, I get two (to my mind) conflicting items.  A file with a single line that says 'Hello, world', and output of 'No'.  To my mind, the `$fh->can` line should return true. Am I wrong here?

Comment: I don't have an answer about why this is acting weird, but I suspect part of it comes from IO::Handle not being a normal class. Some of that is inside the perl source instead of living as a normal module. It might deserve a bug report (use perlbug) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Odd, it looks like you need to create a real [`IO::File`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/File.html) object to get the `can` method to work.  Try

```
use IO::File;

my $fh = IO::File->new("file.out", ">>")
    or die "Couldn't open file: $!";
```

Comment: Used IO::File.  Thanks once again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`IO::Handle` doesn't overload the `open()` function, so you're not actually getting an `IO::Handle` object in `$fh`. I don't know why the `$fh->print("Hello, world")` line works (probably because you're calling the `print()` function, and when you do things like `$foo->function` it's equivalent to `function $foo`, so you're essentially printing to the filehandle like you'd normally expect).

If you change your code to something like:

```
use strict;
use IO::Handle;
open my $fh, ">>", "file.out" or die "Can't open file";
my $iofh = new IO::Handle;
$iofh->fdopen( $fh, "w" );
$iofh->print("Hello, world");
if ($iofh->can("print"))
{
  print "Yes\n";
}
else
{
  print "No\n";
}
```

...then your code will do as you expect. At least, it does for me!

Comment: Why are you using `open` + `fdopen` instead of just using `IO::File`?

Comment: Because I didn't know about `IO::File` until I saw Chas' reply. I had `IO::Handle` on the brain because that's what I thought the OP wanted to use.

Comment: I also didn't know about IO::File until I looked it up just now.  Thanks for your help once again!  Always a learning experience.